# How to concatenate two string columns or a literal to string column using 1.4 DF API (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

When I try to concatenate two string columns or a literal with a string column using the "+" function, the result is always null.

```
auction.select(col("item") ) show

+----+
|item|
+----+
|xbox|
+----+
```

So the column is just fine.  But the + operator always yields null.  I can't find a `concat` function in the 1.4 API.

```
auction.select(col("item") + col("item")) show

+-------------+
|(item + item)|
+-------------+
|         null|
+-------------+
```

Same is true with a literal

```
auction.select(lit("Blue ") + col("item")) show


+--------------+
|(Blue  + item)|
+--------------+
|          null|
+--------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always register your DataFrame as a table and then query it through SQL:

```
auction.registerTempTable("auction")
val concatenated = sqlContext.sql("SELECT CONCAT(item, ' ',  item) FROM auction")
```